# Linking g++ with opengl (glm, glew and freeglut)

Tags: c++, opengl, g++

This is the c++ code I want to run on my computer: http://pastebin.com/66BEyTWK

On the university computer, this code displays a white square. But when I try to run it on my computer all I get is a blank screen.

I read on the opengl faq that the problem might be that I am linking with the wrong combination of opengl libraries.

The include part of the code suggests that I need to link glm, glew and freeglut.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

I read that it is not necessary to link glm, because it is only a header file. So this is the compile statement I came up with:

```
g++ -o main white_square.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLEW
```

At my university they have setup a custom makefile which I can't get much sense out of: http://pastebin.com/3DxST3Xs

Comment: if you think it's the linker flags, check the `LDFLAGS` from that Makefile youÄre using at the university. i.e., try with `-lm -lGL -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGLU -lglut -lGLEW -lXi -lXmu` (adapt /usr/X11R6/lib to wherever you have x11 libraries)

Comment: Do you get the exact same compiler error if you add `int main(){}` after your four lines of `#include`s?  If so, there's an sscce(.org) for you :-)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Hi, this question is from 2013. I no longer use the setup I did back then.

Comment: In case anyone still tries to compile the above program, remove `glutInitContextVersion(3, 1); glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_DEBUG);` and compile by using `-lglew32 -lopengl32 -lglut32`